# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python

```
from googlesearch import search
query = "Taylor Swift"

for i in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):

    import urllib.request
    with urllib.request.urlopen(i) as response:
          html = response.read()
```

This is the error that is showing up

```
C:\Speechtotext>python -u "c:\Speechtotext\web.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open   
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,     
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request      
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders   
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output 
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Speechtotext\web.py", line 7, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen(i) as response:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>
```

I wrote this code about a year and a half back and it ran that time without any difficulties, but today when I tried running it, this showed up
Could not get any proper answers
Please help :)

Comment: Why do you think the certificate has *not* expired?

Comment: ...if you can confirm that the certificate used by the web server being connected to is in fact valid, then you might next look at whether the system clock is accurate on the host where this was observed.